# has_parameter() in callback throws exception

Tags: ros, ros2, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure how this is supposed to be done:

I have a parameter client and the node which is passed to the client spins ...

`rclcpp::spin( paramServer.get_node_base_interface() );`

Now when I get a service callback, and I call the function has_parameter():

`paramClient.has_parameter( paramName )`

I get the exception `Node has already been added to an executor` because inside has_parameter() it does `spin_node_until_future_complete`.

Only solution I can think of is to do it like that:

```
rclcpp::WallRate rate(5);
  while( rclcpp::ok() )
  {
     rclcpp::spin_some( paramServer.get_node_base_interface() );
     rate.sleep();
  }
```

So is it correct that I am not allowed to just spin the node if I want to do such things inside a subclassed node ( `class ParamServer : public rclcpp::Node` )?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333897/has_parameter()-in-callback-throws-exception/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2019-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, stupid me...

I must not use the paramClient inside the node but the node itself to call `has_parameter()`.

`this->has_parameter( name )` instead of `paramClient.has_parameter( name )`

---

Originally posted by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) with karma: 496 on 2019-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0